# How to say the name of this approach clearance: COPTER RNAV (GPS) 027°

Tags: helicopter, approach

JFK has this approach: https://aeronav.faa.gov/d-tpp/2006/00610COPTERR027.PDF

How is this approach said on frequency? Is it the "copter RNAV zero two seven approach" or the "copter RNAV zero two seven degree approach" or the "copter RNAV heading zero two seven approach" or something else?

Comment: Ultimately, i don't think it really matters, as long as ATC can understand what you are saying.

Comment: Degrees is never used on frequency. Could either be temperature or heading so you don't use it. Then the word heading is not required as the control knows what your talking about. The rule is keep it as short and clear as possible. So the first solution would be my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the [7110.65 2–1–17**h**](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/atc_html/chap2_section_4.html), "degrees" is never used. Based on Note 9 under [4–8–1**a**](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/atc_html/chap4_section_8.html), the text in paranthesis is omitted. So, ATC would say:

> Cleared Copter RNAV zero two seven Approach

or

> Cleared Copter RNAV heading zero two seven Approach

If you were requesting it, you'd say "Requesting Copter RNAV zero two seven approach."

However, since it is the only Copter approach at JFK, you could probably just request "the copter approach" and they'd know exactly what you're talking about. But ATC is required to use the phraseology as indicated in the Order linked above.

Answer (score -1):

"Copter RNAV  zero two seven approach"

Comment: Could you add a source? That could also be personal experience with this approach or similar ones. In that case, could you add some more details?